# Flutter load 100+ images from asset

Tags: flutter

I have 100+ images (each not exceeding size more than 100kb) which I am showing on a container.
When I load the images from asset I see in dart tools (memory mode) that the image object + codec object is taking approx 225 mb of memory . I am not sure why. 
Adding code snippet for the image load.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
     @override
     State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

static const List<List<String>> _imageList = <List<String>>[
    <String>['wild', '6D', '7D', '8D', '9D', '10D', 'QD', 'KD', 'AD', 'wild'],
    <String>['5D', '3H', '2H', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', 'AC'],
    <String>['4D', '4H', 'KD', 'AD', 'AC', 'KC', 'QC', '10C', '8S', 'KC'],
    <String>['3D', '5H', 'QD', 'QH', '10H', '9H', '8H', '9C', '9S', 'QC'],
    <String>['2D', '6H', '10D', 'KH', '3H', '2H', '7H', '8C', '10S', '10C'],
    <String>['AS', '7H', '9D', 'AH', '4H', '5H', '6H', '7C', 'QS', '9C'],
    <String>['KS', '8H', '8D', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C', 'KS', '8C'],
    <String>['QS', '9H', '7D', '6D', '5D', '4D', '3D', '2D', 'AS', '7C'],
    <String>['10S', '10H', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C'],
    <String>['wild', '9S', '8S', '7S', '6S', '5S', '4S', '3S', '2S', 'wild']
  ];

  List<Widget> _getHorizontalList(List<String> list) {
        List<Widget> horizontalWidgets = List();
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
              horizontalWidgets.add(
                  Flexible(
                    flex:1,
                    child:Container(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/cards/'+list[i]+'.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                    )
                  )
              );
        }
        return horizontalWidgets;
}

List<Widget> _getVerticallist() {
      List<Widget> verticalWidgets = List();
      for(int i=0;i<_imageList.length;i++) {
          List<String> horizontalList=  _imageList[i];
          verticalWidgets.add(
          Flex(
             direction: Axis.horizontal,
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
             children: _getHorizontalList(horizontalList),
          ));
      }
      return verticalWidgets;
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
         body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 0.95*MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 0.8*MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Flex(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    children: _getVerticallist(),
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                ),
            ),
         ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I would guess that you want to load all 100+ images from the assets folder and I assumed that images is in order e.g. `image_01`, `image_02` so on or might be a random name on the images. I just want to clarify if this is the case in your end?

Comment: @Alvin Quezon yes all 100+ images from asset folder and in the above code value comes from a logic to load certain asset image

Comment: Can you give me an example name of an asset so that I can get a clear picture?

Comment: @Alvin Quezon added complete example in code

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have another list of strings inside a list of string so the only thing you have to do is loop again inside the string like this.

```dart
for(int i = 0; i < _imageList.length; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < _imageList[i].length; j++) {
      horizontalWidgets.Add(
         Flexible (
            flex: 1,
            child: Container (
               child: Image.asset('assets/cards/'+list[i][j]+'.png',fit: BoxFit.contain,),
            )
         )
      )
   }
}
```